# Really simple. XML feed + Freemarker template = HTML, but how?

Tags: xml, templates, rss, freemarker, feed

I'm new to Freemarker, parsing, and StackOverflow, and I'm frustrated, so bear with me here, please...

I have an RSS XML feed (I think, it's a link kinda like this: http://www.blog.com/?fm=rss), the tree is simple enough:

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <link>http://www.blog.com</link>
    <description>Blog</description>
    <item>
      <title>
        My Blog
      </title>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I have a Freemarker template which calls on the feed:

```
<div>
  <#list rss.channel.item as item>
    <h1>${item.title}</h1>
  </#list>
</div>
```

Expecting to see this

```
<div>
  <h1>My Blog</h1>
<div>
```

---

My question is simple: how do I connect the two? what do I need to do? I have no clue, and please explain it to me like I'm five - I've read the [Freemarker documentation section on XML](http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html) - it says "Assume that the programmer has put the XML document into the data-model as variable doc." Can we not assume this time?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the `org.w3c.dom.Document` or `org.w3c.dom.Element` object into the data-model, just like anything else. At least if you left the `object_wrapper` setting on its default, it will recognize it. You may want to apply `NodeModel.simplify(Node)` on the value though.